# ClassNotFoundException: Of Module inside a library project's AAR file

Tags: android, aar

I have library project which depends on multiple modules. I have exported an AAR file of the library project and want to use in APP. ClassNotFoundException occurring for the class that is inside the module which is inside my library project.

> Do I need to use all the other module's aar file in the APP?
>
> How can I use all the modules which is inside my main library project.

Comment: You might want to add the library project instead of selecting individual files - the issue with that, as you have experienced it, is that there may be dependencies between classes.

Comment: modules are not getting bundled in one AAR file. I Unzipped the aar and checked it.